# Is it possible to use GNU extensions unless pedantic?

Tags: c++, gcc, conditional-compilation, gcc-pedantic

Is there a way to conditionally enable features that rely on GCC extensions (such as `__int128`) if they would compile?

I want to do something like

```cpp
void foo(int);
void foo(long);
void foo(long long);
#if not_pedantic
void foo(__int128);
#endif
```

I could not find a macro that is defined when `-pedantic` or `pedantic-error` is passed.

Comment: I would whip up something with autoconf and automake, that tries a test compile, and then uses it to set a `#define`.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You should provide the overload if the compiler supports this type, regardless of pedantic settings. Wrap it in `#pragma`s or use `__extension__` to silence compiler warnings. As a person who builds with `-pedantic-errors`, but adds compiler extensions as needed by temporarily disabling the warnings, I would be quite unhappy if a library pulled off what you're trying to do.

Comment: There's no such macro on clang `diff <(command clang -xc /dev/null -E -dM  ) <(command clang -xc /dev/null  -E -dM -pedantic)`  or gcc `diff <(c gcc -xc /dev/null -E -dM  ) <(c gcc -xc /dev/null  -E -dM -pedantic)`.
`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How do I use `__extension__` in this case? What I’ve found tells me: Write it before an expression, but what about function declarations?

Comment: I've posted an answer showing it.

Comment: Pass it in on your compile line: `g++ -DGNU_PEDANTIC=1 -pedantic a.cpp -o a.out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Only check the compiler, and disable the `-pedantic-errors` warnings with `#pragma`s or `__extension__`:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(long);
void foo(long long);
#ifdef __GNUC__
__extension__ void foo(__int128);
#endif
```

If your user builds with `-pedantic-errors` but still uses the extensions as needed, they would be very annoyed if you disable overloads like this.

Answer (score 3):

gcc offers [`__STRICT_ANSI__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) that is defined if you have set `-ansi` or `-std=c++XX` (as opposed to `-std=gnu++XX` which enables extensions). This does not check for `-pedantic`, only for the flags that were mentioned:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(long);
void foo(long long);
#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__
void foo(__int128);
#endif
```

I don't see any way to check for `-pedantic` specifically. There doesn't seem to be any macro or pragma that allows checking (not setting) specific compiler flags.